# Find the value(s) of parameter $a$ for which a certain matrix isn't diagonalizable in complex field

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

> $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&0&-a-1\\
> 1&1&0&0\\
> 0&1&1&a+2\\
> 0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ can not be diagonalizable in complex field, find $a$.

What's the idea? Intuititively, $a=-1$ or $a=-2$, so some entries of the matrix is zero$, but using mathematical software, it is  diagonalizable!

What is needed for this type problem? I find no such ideas from the books, and though hard to find nothing. Help.

Comment: Your intuition does not make sense. A matrix is *not* diagonalizable if there's a eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity greater than geometric multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

A square matrix is diagonalizable, if it is a [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix), that is, it commutes with its adjoint matrix, the matrix transposed with complex conjugate entries.

The example A yields a constant -4 at position (2,2) for the commutator, independent of the choice of a.

$$ A A^* - A^* A =\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 (a+1) a^*+a+4 & 0 & 2-(a+1) \left(a^*+2\right) & 0 \\
 0 & -4 & 0 & a \\
 2-(a+2) \left(a^*+1\right) & 0 & (a+2) \left(a^*+2\right) & 0 \\
 0 & a^* & 0 & -(2 a+3) a^*-3 a-4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$